# Change SMS Sender ID in SMS in Twilio?

Tags: sms, sender-id

I want to change my **SMS** Sender ID Name so User can known about sender.
Actually,when i send sms to user.User can see different Id of mine so they confuse about message so i want to set **Fix** Sender ID so user can know about who can send message in **Twilio**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According Twillio you can't

[Twillio FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-i-display-a-business-name-or-custom-text-as-my-caller-id)